# Blazor AOT fails with "The command "emcc --version" exited with code -1073741515"

Tags: .net, blazor, aot

I'm trying to run the publishing of the Blazor application.
I have installed DotNet6 Preview6, AOT workload.

When I run publishing, I get the next error message:

> C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\6.0.0-preview.6.21352.12\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(316,5):
> error MSB3073: The command "emcc --version" exited with code
> -1073741515.

What can be a reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found the reason. It happens because emcc can not run Python, which is located at C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.2.0.21.Python.win-x64\6.0.0-preview.6.21275.1\tools . This package includes Python 3.9, and it does not work on Windows Server 2008R2.

The solution: we need to migrate to a recent Windows Server.

Temporary Workaround: in the file C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.2.0.21.Python.win-x64\6.0.0-preview.6.21275.1\Sdk\Sdk.props override the variable EMSDK_PYTHON and point it to python 3.8

Answer (score 4):

To publish on .net 7 under Linux, the following command helps:

> apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 && dotnet workload install wasm-tools